# What framework Cloud9 uses to make the interface (treelist, windows, etc)?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, cloud9-ide

If they don't use framework, please could you show me a path to build a interface like that? Tutorials, books, videos, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9 use their own UI platform, called APF: https://github.com/ajaxorg/apf.

There are a few articles about how to use the tree component, etc., in their developer documentation: https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/ace-tree.

APF is probably not the tool you are looking for. There are a lot of frameworks out there for building rich web UIs. If you want recommendations on which one to use, I suggest you ask a more open question, stating what it is you are trying to achieve.